# Connect to MSSQL with USB in android

Tags: android, jdbc

```
private void fillCustomerInformationFields() throws  SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String IDValue = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    String query = "SELECT  SiparisID, M.MusteriAdi + ' ' + M.MusteriSoyadi AS MusteriAdi, U.UrunAdi," +
            " CASE WHEN OdemeTuru=0 THEN ? WHEN OdemeTuru=1 THEN ? WHEN OdemeTuru=2 THEN ? END AS OdemeTuru, TeslimTarihi,"+
    "M.musteriAdresi, SiparisDurumu, Aciklama FROM Siparisler S INNER JOIN Musteriler M ON M.MusteriID=S.MusteriID INNER JOIN Urunler U ON U.UrunID=S.urunID"+
    "WHERE S.SiparisID='"+IDValue+"'";

    try {
        conn = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,"Peşin");
        preparedStatement.setString(2,"Taksitli");
        preparedStatement.setString(3,"Kapıda");
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            edtSiparisID.setText(resultSet.getString("SiparisID"));
            edtUrunAdi.setText(resultSet.getString("UrunAdi"));
            edtMusteriAdi.setText(resultSet.getString("MusteriAdi"));
            edtOdemeTuru.setText(resultSet.getString("OdemeTuru"));
            edtTeslimTarihi.setText(resultSet.getString("TeslimTarihi"));
            edtSiparisAdresi.setText(resultSet.getString("musteriAdresi"));
            edtAciklama.setText(resultSet.getString("Aciklama"));
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(preparedStatement != null){
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        if(conn != null){
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**Hello everyone. İ'm making a project and i connect to mssql from android app via usb. I wrote to code for read data from mssql but i'm getting error.  how can i fix the error? Thanks for the help**

The exception displayed in LogCat is:

```
com.example.uur.stock W/System.err﹕ java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'S'.
```

Comment: 05-21 23:13:25.040  19042-19042/com.example.uur.stock W/System.err﹕ java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'S'.

Answer (score 1):

Check your query

```
String query = "SELECT  SiparisID, M.MusteriAdi + ' ' + M.MusteriSoyadi AS MusteriAdi, U.UrunAdi," +
            " CASE WHEN OdemeTuru=0 THEN ? WHEN OdemeTuru=1 THEN ? WHEN OdemeTuru=2 THEN ? END AS OdemeTuru, TeslimTarihi,"+
    "M.musteriAdresi, SiparisDurumu, Aciklama FROM Siparisler S INNER JOIN Musteriler M ON M.MusteriID=S.MusteriID INNER JOIN Urunler U ON U.UrunID=S.urunID"+
    "WHERE S.SiparisID='"+IDValue+"'";
```

this is causing the exception:

```
FROM Siparisler S JOIN Musteriler M
```

must change to

```
FROM Siparisler as S JOIN Musteriler as M
```

More info:

[**SQLite - ALIAS Syntax**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_alias_syntax.htm)

Comment: probably you have more errors in your query, post your error messages displayed in LogCat